# ¿A que fase del desarrollo de software apoya el diagrama UML de actividad?

Tags: diseño, uml

Tengo entendido que los diferentes diagramas que pueden existir de UML se utilizan para las diferentes etapas del ciclo de vida de software. Quisiera saber en qué fase del ciclo de vida de software se utilizan principalmente los diagramas de actividad.

Un saludo. :)

Comment: Haz leido el manual de UML? a que te refieres con fase del ciclo de vida de desarrollo? estos diagramas se hacen durante el analisis del sistema.

Comment: Sí, entiendo que estos se hagan durante el análisis del sistema. Por  las fases del ciclo a por ejemplo si describen el diseño del sistema, si sirve para apoyar a la programación del mismo o así dependiendo de la fase.

Comment: Este diagrama describe al sistema. No estaria comprendiendo tu pregunta. Todos los diagramas uml sirven para apoyar la programacion del mismo. Un caso de uso por ejemplo describe como debe comportarse el sistema, por lo tanto tambien describe como debe progrmarse. Creo que estas confundiendo el ciclo de vida del software (prueba de concepto, desarrollo, mantenimiento) con otra cosa.